# Do I need to free objects returned from gtk_builder_get_object?

Tags: gtk

I am new to GTK and all its terminology and the docs could be better.
I have the following controls I need to clear on a button click.

- GTKTextView - 1
- GTKEntry - 3
- GTKLabel - 16

So I was thinking I would loop through a table of object names calling gtk_builder_get_object and saving the returned object (these are like handles in windows?).  Do I have to free these when I am done, or do they get destroyed when my window closes?

Comment: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question very much, are you trying to destroy widgets? If so, you should use [gtk_widget_destroy ()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-destroy).

> When a widget is destroyed, it will break any references it holds to
>   other objects. If the widget is inside a container, the widget will be
>   removed from the container. If the widget is a toplevel (derived from
>   GtkWindow), it will be removed from the list of toplevels, and the
>   reference GTK+ holds to it will be removed.

If you destroy a window, the widgets on it will also be destroyed. If you want to destroy certain widgets in a window, destroy their parent (e.g. a box or table in which they are packed). Otherwise, you'll have to destroy them one by one.

> In most cases, only toplevel widgets (windows) require explicit destruction, because when you destroy a toplevel its children will be destroyed as well.

In gtk, you don't free pointers to widgets if that is what you meant, Gtk functions do that for you appropriately.

Please let me know if I can be of more help...